# PHP, MySQL | Таблицы, ошибка при выводе данных

Tags: php, mysql, таблицы

Не работает вывод данных из таблицы, хотя раньше работало.
Как можно пофиксить?

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "u_base", "123", "u_base");
  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    if ((isset($_GET['key']))) {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `base1` WHERE `key`=".$key;
      $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
      $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
      echo $myrow['date'];
      echo $myrow['id'];
      echo 'ok';
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная $key вы её не объявили. Должно быть $_GET["key"]

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "u_base", "123", "u_base");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

if ((isset($_GET['key']))) {

$key = $_GET["key"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `base1` WHERE `key`=".$key;
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo $myrow['date'];
echo $myrow['id'];
echo 'ok';
```

Comment: Ну хоть бы парой слов sql-инъекцию упомянули для приличия

Comment: Вопрос был не в том как безопасно а почему не работает. А так да, от SQL инъекций нужно защищаться.